# Basic Angular - How to load json http response into another json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, currency-exchange-rates

I am using fixer.io and money.js to convert currency. money.js is used to convert currency and fixer.io is an api that gets the latest exchange rates. I need to load the latest exchange rates into the money.js rates object.

Because I'm using angular, money.js is loaded like:

```
var fx = require("money");
```

In order for conversion to work, we have to define `fx.base` and `fx.rates` like this:

```
fx.base = "USD";
fx.rates = {
    "EUR" : 0.745101, // eg. 1 USD === 0.745101 EUR
    "GBP" : 0.647710, // etc...
    "HKD" : 7.781919,
    "USD" : 1,        // always include the base rate (1:1)
    /* etc */
}
```

However, rather than hardcoded data for `fx.rates` to be populated from a GET request to the fixer.io API, which will return this JSON:
http://api.fixer.io/latest

I'm a total noob to angular so I don't understand how to load a json response into another json object.

What is the right way to do something like :

```
var response = $http.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest");
fx.rates = response;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy, using the [`http` promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in Angular. To handle a promise, you use the `.then` method. All you need is a callback function to handle the data. :

```
var response = $http.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest");

//handle promise
response.then(function(response) {
  //this is response from the api fixer. The data is the body payload
  fx.rates = response.data;
}, function(error) {
  //handle error here, if there is any.
});
```

Here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y1tywgxFRJI5T2dy5P3z?p=preview), if you need it.

Comment: Does this work even if the json includes other fields? If you look at the Json response for that URL, it also includes a base attribute and a date attribute, and then the rates. So isn't what I really need more like `fx.rates = response.data.rates`

Comment: One more question- also does the $http promise have to be in a controller?

Comment: Yes. The response.data includes every thing in the payload body. So if the data has 1000 properties, it will contain every single one of them. $http is a service that is injected into the controller, as shown in the plnkr